# Calling a Perl program from PHP and printing the output

Tags: php, perl, system

For a school project I want to try scanning websites for vulnerabilities, and show the responds on a page.

For this I am trying to use Uniscan.

I tried a lot of ways to get any responds but it isn't working out.

This is what I have right now:

```
   <?php
echo '<pre>';

// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = system('perl uniscan.pl -u https://domain.nl/ -qweds;ls', $ret$

// Printing additional info
echo '</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

This is the responds, the only thing you see is the responds of the 'ls' command.

[image: Responds]

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Then why are you running `ls` then?

Comment: just to see if I get any responds

Comment: So what do you expect then?

Comment: `system` gives you output of last executed command which is `ls`

Comment: I want to get the responds of the command perl uniscan.pl -u https://domain.nl/ -qweds;

Comment: So __remove__ `ls` from `system` call, isn't it?

Comment: Than I get no responds, and before the ls I am already running the command that I want

Comment: @NielsvanderKnaap: Please do not post images if text output. Text should be included in your question as text. I don't understand why so many people think that images of text are useful.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `uniscan.pl`, but is it possible that it's sending its output to *stderr* instead of *stdout*? What happens if you run that perl command line from your shell, and redirect output somewhere? And what does your web server's error log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the www-data user didn't had rights to run that script.

So when I gave him right in the sudoers file like this:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/Uniscan/uniscan.pl
```

everything works perfectly!

Comment: Good. Consider accepting your answer so that question doesn't appear in `unanswered` list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have poorly copied the code from http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php.

In addition to that your code has syntax errors. You passed `$ret` to system but tried to print `$retval`. Also the closing parenthesis is missing.

Try this:

```
$last_line = system('/usr/bin/perl uniscan.pl -u https://domain.nl/ -qweds', $retval);
```

Note that I have provided absolute path of perl interpreter.

Comment: Good suggestions, though I'd advise against recommending an absolute path for perl unless you know that it'll work in the OP's operating system. Perl isn't always located in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Still not working :/

This is the he responds I get:
Last line of the output:
Return value: 13